# React-Native Accelerometer Can't get the upside down to work

Tags: react-native, accelerometer, react-native-ios

I have created this if and else if statements. Flat, Vertical, Facedown, Right Side, and Left Side work... However, I am not sure why the Upside down is not working. Here is my code:

`checkOrientation= () => {
    let orientation = "unknown";
    if (z > .8 && Math.abs(x) < .2 && Math.abs(y) < .2) orientation = "flat";
    else if (y > .9 && Math.abs(x) < .2 &&Math.abs(z) < .2) orientation = "vertical";
    if (x < .1 && Math.abs(y) < .1 && Math.abs(z) < .3) orientation = "right side";
    else if (z < .01 && Math.abs(x) > .9 && Math.abs(y) < .05) orientation = "left side";
    if (x > .01 && Math.abs(y) < .7 && Math.abs(z) < .05) orientation = "upside down";
    else if (x > .01 && Math.abs (y) < .01 && Math.abs(z) > .01) orientation = "face down";
    this.setState({orientation});
  }`

Comment: You can use an else block to declare any position outside of the 5 you listed as "upside down"